How to get this badge?
Publicist Badge:
"Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses"
What exactly does this mean? Should I share a question 1000 times and get 1000 views from it, or is it just to share any popular question once?

I believe it's 1000 visits on one link you post. I don't think it cares about the referer so visits on the same link from different places should count. @anahevesi probably knows best.
